# Google Cloud Platform / Firebase Function not triggering with onWrite

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My application makes use of [Firestore Function Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to perform background actions based on changes in the Firestore, e.g. user profile changes. For example, if they change their mobile number, a verification code is sent.

I have a trigger that should run when an [onWrite()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#onwrite) event happens on a specific collection. `onWrite()` runs when any of the following actions occur in Firebase on a specific collection:

- [onCreate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#oncreate)
- [onUpdate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#onupdate)
- [onDelete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#ondelete)

In my usecase, I need it to run for `onCreate()` and `onUpdate()`, thus I use `onWrite()`

For [Firebase Triggers to work](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing-triggered_functions), a specific format is expected in addition to a document id/wildcard representing a document that was created/changed/deleted.

**Constants:**

```
const collections = {
    ...
    conversations: "conversations",
    ...
}
```

**Callable Function** (updates firestore):

```
/**
 * Add an conversation to conversations collection
 * @type {HttpsFunction & Runnable<any>}
 */
exports.addConversations = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =>  {
    // expects conversation & interested state
    const {valid, errors} = validateRequiredBody(data, [
        "conversation",
    ]);
    if (!valid) {
        return {
            status: false,
            message: "Missing or invalid parameters",
            errors: errors,
            jwtToken: "",
        };
    }

    // get conversation item
    const conversation = {
        id: data["conversation"]["id"],
        name: data["conversation"]["name"],
    }

    // create conversation with empty counter
    // let writeResult = await collectionRefs.conversationsRef.doc(conversation.id).set({
    let writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection(collections.conversations).doc(conversation.id).set({
        id: conversation.id,
        name: conversation.name,
        count: 0
    });
    console.log(`[function-addConversations] New Conversation [${conversation.name}] added`);

    return {
        status: true,
        message: ""
    }
});
```

**Firestore Trigger** (not triggering):

```
/**
 * On conversations updated/removed, update corresponding counter
 * @type {CloudFunction<Change<QueryDocumentSnapshot>>}
 */
exports.onConversationProfileCollectionCreate = functions.firestore.document(`${collections.conversations}/{id}`)
    .onWrite(async snapshot => {
        console.log("Conversation Collection Changed");
        // let conversation = collectionRefs.conversationsRef.doc(snapshot.id);
        // await conversation.update({count: FieldValue.increment(1)});
    });
```

In my mobile application, the user (calls) the `addConversations()` firebase function, this adds the new conversation to Firestore which is clearly visible, but the counter trigger (trigger function) doesn't run.

**Emulator output:**

```
...
{"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"INFO","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
[function-addConversations] New Conversation [Test Conversation Topic] added
Profile updated 
(print profile data)
...
```

**What I SHOULD expect to see:**

```
...
{"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"INFO","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
[function-addConversations] New Conversation [Test Conversation Topic] added
Conversation Collection Changed      // this is output by the trigger
Profile updated 
(print profile data)
...
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Do you see anything from the function execution in the log? E.g. `onConversationProfileCollectionCreate Function execution started`

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec no. I have a profile `onWrite()` trigger that outputs `Profile Updated`, but nothing else in the standard terminal output. Do you have a suggestion how I can enable verbose logging?

Comment: What happens if you try to deploy the Cloud Functions?

Comment: Maybe the collection name is being declared improperly or something. Have you checked if `${collections.conversations}` has the value you expect it to have? Also, are there any errors popping in the firebase-debug.log?

Comment: @RafaelLemos no errors in `firebase-debug.log`, also I added the `${collections.conversations}` as a constant *(see above the callable function section of my post and uses of this constant throughout my example/application)*

Comment: About 3 days ago, I created a firebase function which worked  by the callable API function  but the triggering function didn't work.

Comment: When you tested this on your system, did you make sure that your Cloud Functions were [writing to the emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#instrument_your_app_for_callable_functions) and not your live database?

Comment: @samthecodingman a very good suggestion, very close infact that I would say you have the correct answer. The issue I just noticed while working on another project is I had firestore & rtdb in production (dev ofc) while auth, functions, etc was running locally. Thus the listeners didn't run since firestore/rtdb wasn't emulated locally

Comment: @samthecodingman feel free to post a solution - your comment put me on the right track

Comment: @samthecodingman ensuring firebase & database is running locally, those triggers on database/firestore creates, updates, etc still do not trigger - even after ensuring they are running and that I'm writing to the interested & listened to collections

Comment: @CybeX When you call `addConversations`, are you changing what you send each time? If you use `addConversations({ conversation: { id: "convo1", name: "Tim's chat"}})` over and over, you won't trigger the `onWrite` function because the document `/conversations/convo1` hasn't changed (even though it may have been overwritten).

Comment: @samthecodingman see solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The issue was one closer to home.*

I am developing using the [firebase emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup) and connecting to them using the emulators addition in Flutter's firebase packages built in [emulator feature](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/testing/testing/#integration-tests-using-the-firestore-emulator).

Firebase emulator setup e.g. [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)

**TL;DR:**

When starting your Firebase emulator, you should see something similar to:

```
C:\Users\User\MyApp\awesome-app-server>firebase emulators:start --only functions
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
!  functions: You are running the functions emulator in debug mode (port=9229). This means that functions will execute in sequence rather than in parallel.
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
!  Your requested "node" version "12" doesn''t match your global version "14"
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\User\MyApp\awesome-app-server\functions" for Cloud Functions...
>  Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/03dc1d62-f2a3-418e-a343-bb0b357f7329
>  Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/03dc1d62-f2a3-418e-a343-bb0b357f7329
>  For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
!  functions: The Realtime Database emulator is not running, so calls to Realtime Database will affect production.

...
```

BUT then you see this - **THIS is very important!**

```
i  functions[us-central1-api-user-onConversationProfileCollectionCreate ]: function ignored because the database emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

*This, since Firestore & (Realtime) Database use triggers which are found in functions, functions expects to find a local firestore/database emulator.*

Since **no firestore/database emulators were running locally**

```
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
!  functions: The Realtime Database emulator is not running, so calls to Realtime Database will affect production.
```

and these functions don't *automagically* attach to production Firestore/Database(s) (*that would be potentially devestating*), these triggers didn't run when I expected them to while **emulating** locally.

**Solution:**

1. Emulate firestore & database locally (see [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-import-production-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-the-local-emulator-e82ae1c6ed8) to import your firestore data to a local emulator) with `firebase emulators:start --only functions,...,firestore,database`
2. Upload functions to work with Firestore/Database(s) (***please do this with care***)

---

**More details:**

Below I provide details what lead me to the problem, and how I figured out the issue:

**What I was doing:**

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --only functions,auth
```

- [local] Firebase Functions I was developing and testing the backend for my mobile app using Firebase Functions for various interactivity.
- Since [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) is handled locally through the use of [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) on my firebase functions app, I used local auth for testing

I had prepopulated my Firestore with data, thus I intended to use Firestore data while emulating locally which had worked as expected, BUT the firebase firestore & database triggers won't work due to emulating them locally.

*I knew some of my triggers **DID** infact trigger correctly, thus it must be a configuration error of some kind.*

**Extended Solution** (*import firestore data to local emulator*)

firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --only functions,auth,firestore,database

*notice the last 2, firestore & database - this should be added for triggers to work locally*

- I noticed when reviewing the logs at startup, the text indicating some functions won't run. This made me realize I was making a crucial mistake - the cause.

**Import Data from production firestore**

The reason for using production (during development) firestore is to not recreate all the data for each test. The solution is to export from firestore and import you data to the emulators.

See this for [details](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-import-production-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-the-local-emulator-e82ae1c6ed8) - I wasn't able to export from the terminal, I thus went to Google Console to export to a storage bucket, and download it via the console from there.

To start the emulator (and allow debugging of firebase functions), I use:

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --import ./functions/{path/to/data} --only functions,auth,firestore,database
```

details:

- `firebase emulators:start` - start emulator
- `--inspect-functions` allow debugging functions via websockets - e.g. Webstorm NodeJs debugger on port 9229
- `--import ./functions/{path/to/data}` - import data to firestore emulator using project root as `./`
- `--only functions,auth,firestore,database` specify the modules to emulate

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong value. snapshot works only for onDelete and onCreate method

```js
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // If we set `/users/marie` to {name: "Marie"} then
       context.params.userId == "marie"
      // ... and ...
      change.after.data() == {name: "Marie"}
    });
```

for more info read here [feedbackCloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: From a firebase example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#define_a_function_trigger

Comment: I added the link. That is why I said "for more info read here"

Comment: ah - I see the confusion. `snapshot` in the context of `.onWrite(async snapshot => {` can cause confusion, but this is fundamentally just a variable name such as context, change, etc. This was not the underlying cause/reason for it no to work - your suggestion is merely aesthetics. See my posted answer for the cause and solution.